# Microsoft BotBuilder - TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/app.ts(10,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'botbuilder-teams'

Tags: typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm running this project https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/tree/master/samples/teams-bot and getting into the following error and not sure how to go about fixing it; I tried installing the missing module with

> npm install botbuilder-teams@4.0.0-beta1 and
>
> npm install botbuilder-teams@4.0.0-beta1 --save

but still got same issue:

```
> npm start
> botbuilder-teams-js-teams-bot@0.0.1 start /home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot
> npm run build:live


> botbuilder-teams-js-teams-bot@0.0.1 build:live /home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot
> nodemon --ignore './data' --exec node --inspect=5566 -r ts-node/register ./src/app.ts

[nodemon] 1.19.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect=5566 -r ts-node/register ./src/app.ts`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5566/4e05909b-00a5-4bcb-9581-57e9e08fe185
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts(10,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'botbuilder-teams'.

    at createTSError (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261:12)
    at getOutput (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:367:40)
    at Object.compile (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:558:11)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/samples/teams-bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
```

Comment: Could you please try running `npm install` in ~\BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node\botbuilder-teams-js\ directory? Teams Package in sample code is referenced from ["file:../../botbuilder-teams-js"](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/blob/master/samples/teams-bot/package.json#L12)

Comment: @pelican, Can you please confirm if this is resolved or not?

Comment: Sure let me check now, thanks again will report here shortly

Comment: My OS is: `Ubuntu 18.04` - this was most likely tested on Windows but I doubt the OS has anything to do with it. 
So after `npm i` in `botbuilder-teams-js/` I `cd` back out to the `samples/teams-bot/` samples and run `npm i` but I get this error: 
The logs are too large to paste here; here's the link with my error logs: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/tYXhK9ah

Comment: Ok it seemed to be a problem with `node_modules/.staging` not being created; I deleted the `package-lock.json` and reran `npm i` and that step passed :) moving on to running `npm start` will report here of the results

Comment: Ok so was able to get npm start to start on localhost:3978; not sure what the bot is supposed to do; anything I say to teams-bot it echos back to me; is that proper behavior? I am looking for more of a proactive bot that can notify a group of people when certain api events occur

Comment: Ok I finally got it in the code; there's basically a switch statement in the bot.ts file; so I sent comments like "members" "1:1" but how can I make it be more proactive; I'll figure it out - thanks again!